# What's the most efficient method of obtaining a topologically ordered Function list?

Tags: llvm, topological-sort

Suppose we have a module containing some functions with no recursive calls (so the call-graph is a DAG). What is the most efficient method of obtaining a vector of Function*'s from the module ordered by topologcal order in terms of call order?
By topological order I mean that if foo() calls bar() then foo will appear before bar in the sorted list.
Is there any Analysis pass which can give me this info, or do i have to write my own sorting routine?

Comment: Implementing topological sort is not hard... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: I agree, but using an existing analysis pass is even more not hard.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not familiar with an existing pass that does *exactly* what you want, there's code in LLVM that's very close and I'm sure you can use it to solve your problem quickly. It's in the IPA (Inter-procedural analysis) library, in `lib/Analysis/IPA`. In particular, look at `lib/Analysis/IPA/CallGraph.cpp` - it builds a call graph in a module. Sorting such a graph topologically should be fairly easy.